# Configurable route prefix for controller

Tags: asp.net-core, asp.net-routing

I'm using ASP.NET Core 6 and trying to have the base path of my API controller be configurable (so that users can choose the base path themselves to avoid conflicts with other controllers).

I tried setting up the following route:

```
string configurablePrefix = "/temp";
endpoint.MapControllerRoute(
    name: "MyRouteName",
    pattern: configurablePrefix + "/{action=MyDefaultAction},
    defaults: new { controller = "MyController" });
```

Where `MyController` is defined like this:

```
[ApiController]
public class MyController : ControllerBase
{
    [HttpGet("MyDefaultAction")]
    public IActionResult MyDefaultAction()
    {
        return new JsonResult("Hello");
    }
}
```

This causes no errors during startup, but when I access `https://localhost/temp/MyDefaultAction I get a 404

How can I get this to work so that actions in `MyController` are accessible on whatever start path the user chooses (i.e. change it to respond to `/othertemp/MyDefaultAction` instead)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From your code, you are using `ApiController`, which cannot be routed by setting the corresponding route in `Startup.cs` or `Program.cs`.

`ApiController` must have attribute routing, and attribute routing has a higher priority than conventional routing, so it will override the conventional routing you defined.

You can choose to use attribute routing to define the controller name as `temp`, so that the corresponding endpoint can be matched in `ApiController`:

```
[Route("temp")]
[ApiController]
public class MyController : ControllerBase
{
    [HttpGet("MyDefaultAction")]
    public IActionResult MyDefaultAction()
    {
        return new JsonResult("Hello");
    }
}
```

Test Result:

[image]

Or use an MVC controller:

```
public class MyController : Controller
{
    [HttpGet]
    public IActionResult MyDefaultAction()
    {
        return new JsonResult("Hello");
    }
}
```

Routing:

```
string configurablePrefix = "/temp";
endpoint.MapControllerRoute(
    name: "MyRouteName",
    pattern: configurablePrefix + "/{action}",
    defaults: new { controller = "My", action = "MyDefaultAction" });
```

Test Result:

[image]

reference link: [Create web APIs with ASP.NET Core](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/web-api/?view=aspnetcore-7.0#attribute-routing-requirement).

Comment: I completely missed that requirement for `ApiController`. Thanks for the help :)